# UIPageViewController can not be paged programmatically after aborted page

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

My app has a button that programmatically pages a UIPageViewController.

When that button is pressed paging is initiated with `[self setViewControllers:@[nextVc] direction:direction animated:YES completion:nil];`

If the user quickly taps the button and then another part of the screen then the paging operation is aborted just after it is started (which is OK with me).

The problem is that after that point any programmatic page operation does not work. The UIPageViewDelegate's `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` are not even called.

I confirmed in the debugger that even though the page operation was aborted, the UIPageViewController's `viewControllers` property contains the viewcontroller that is not being shown.

Paging the page view with a left or right swipe fixes the internal state of the page view and from then on programmatic paging works again.

I'm using IOS 9.